# Rails Google Api to Display map in homepage with points saved in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-api

I have a project that have a model named Monument. In this model i have the longitude and latitude attributes.

when I add a monument with an longitude and a latitude, the coordinates can be found by clicking in the google map.

But i Have a question.

Can i use the google map API to display ( in my homepage ) the points that i saved for every monument? Something like do an select all points from database and display in the map?

[image: This is a sample from the new.hmtl.erb view. I click in the google map api and the longitude and latitude goes to the fields.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code:

```
<iframe id="map"  width="100%" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=gateshead&aq=&sll=54.9489662,-1.6148245&sspn=0.149605,0.338173&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=169+Saltwell+Rd,+Gateshead,+Tyne+and+Wear+NE8+4XH,+Kerajaan+Inggris&ll=54.9489662,-1.6148245&spn=0.299124,0.676346&t=m&z=11&output=embed"></iframe>
```

Add your lat lang in above url

Comment: Sorry i don't understand where i need to put that code

Comment: Put it in your file with extension .html.erb in views folder

Comment: I implemented that code, but this is hard coded, if i create a new monument i need to hard coded this part. Is possible in someway do a query on the DB and return the values of longitude and latitude of all monuments?

Comment: use google map gem ie https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails